# In Exc vba can i filter out rows that have R/F/U in an alph/nmric cell eg 1F3U.Code ok if I put f and/or u but if I put the 3 in an array then zero

Tags: excel, vba

Here is a sample of what I have tried so far

```
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1:AW1").AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:="<>*f*", Operator:=xlAnd,_ Criteria2:="<>*u*" ' this works
    .Range("A1:AW1").AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:="<>*f*" 'this works
    .Range("A1:AW1").AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:=Array_("<>*r*", "<>*f*", "<>*u*") ' this doesn't
```

Comment: Most likely only 2 criteria for "does not contain" is available in autofilter

Answer (score 1):

You may have to create a loop to hide rows if you are using more than 2 criteria, for example, this will loop through column Z and hide rows that contain r,f,u.

```
Sub HideStuff()
    Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range, C As Range

    LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range("Z2:Z" & LstRw)

    For Each C In Rng.Cells
        If C Like "*f*" Or C Like "*u*" Or C Like "*r*" Then
            C.EntireRow.Hidden = 1
        End If
    Next C


End Sub
```

Comment: Dave, I didn't mention that there were 88,000 lines but running your loop after the rest of the filters works a treat.